# How installation works?

Tags: window, exe

I want to know how installation in windows works like what sort of files get created first as .dll , drivers & all.

To be more precise when we click on .exe file what happens internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, **anything** can happen after you click the exe. But most of the time, installer does some or most of these:

- check if the needed frameworks and libraries are already installed (ex: .NET framework)
- create a registry entry with the application settings and uninstaller path
- extract the binaries and assets or download them
- create the needed directories (ex: Program Files/SomeProgram) and move the extracted files to the proper folders
- create a desktop shortcut
- associate the file extensions with the program
- do whatever else the program needs.. It really depends on what you are installing and what needs to be set up for the program to
  function properly.